Proof on two equal closures
This is quite simple but it seems that I lack some simple piece to make it work.
Given $A \subseteq V$, prove that
$$\overline{A} \cap V \cap \overline{A^c} = \overline{A} \cap V \cap \overline{V \setminus A}$$
My attempt. It is clear why
$$x \in (V \cap \overline{V \setminus A} \cap \overline{A}) \Rightarrow x \in (V \cap \overline{A^c} \cap \overline{A})$$
since $V \setminus A \subseteq A^{c}$. So, any ball with any radius intersects $V \setminus A$, it must intersect $A^{c}$. But conversely, I can't figure out why
$$x \in (V \cap \overline{A^c} \cap \overline{A}) \Rightarrow (x\in V \cap \overline{V \setminus A} \cap \overline{A})$$
It is true that for all $\delta$
$$B(x, \delta) \cap (A^{c}) \neq \emptyset$$
But why does that have to do with
$$B(x, \delta) \cap (V \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$$
The intuitive thing is that $x \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^{c}}$ so it's "pushed" towards the boundary of $A$ and since $A \subseteq V$, it follows that all balls with center $x$ must intersect with $V \setminus A$. So, there exists $a \in \overline{V \setminus A} \cap V \cap \overline{A}$

@geetha290krm Where is $B(X, \delta) \cap V$ deduced from? I do understand that $B(x, \delta)$ is an open neighborhood of  $x$. Is that deduced from the fact that $\forall \delta > 0: B(x, \delta) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$

This is false without any hypothesis on $V$. For a counter-example take $A=V=\{0\}$ in $\mathbb R$. LHS becomes $\{0\}$ and RHS becomes empty.
The result is true if $V$ is open. In that case, $x \in B(x,\delta)\cap V$ and $B(x,\delta)\cap V$ is open. This implies that $B(x,\delta)\cap V$ contains at least one point of $A^{c}$ since $x \in \overline {A^{c}}$.

$V=A$ makes RHS empty. $A^{c}=\mathbb R \setminus {0}$ and the closure of this set is $\mathbb R$. So LHS is ${0}$.   @MichaelBurr

This comes from this equation. Maybe we need the condition $\overline{A}$. Here's the original: $(V \cap \overline{A}) \cap (V \cap \overline{V \setminus A}) = (V \cap \overline{A}) \cap  (V \cap \overline{A^c})$. And of course, $A \subseteq V$

My counter-example also works for what you wrote in the last comment. I think openness of $V$ is understood in your source.

I guess not. It is true that $\partial _{V}A = V \cap \partial  A$, where $\partial _{V}A$ and $\partial  A$ are boundaries of $A$ in $V$ and $R^{n}$. The equation in the question comes from the fact that $\overline{A}^{V} = V \cap \overline{A}$ where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ and $\overline{A}^{V}$ is the closure of $A$ in $V$.

In my example, LHS of your equation is empty because $V\setminus A$ is empty. On RHS $V\cap \overline A={0}$  and $V \cap \overline {A^{c}}=V \cap V=V$ since $\overline {A^{c}}=\mathbb R$.  Why are refusing to do this simple calculation?

This is already answered here. I think the text lacks the condition that V must be open. Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643262/relative-boundary-of-a-in-v-subset-mathbfrn
